# Looking for the name of a science fiction/horror movie or possibly series where a girl is slid head first down a narrowing tube

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, horror, science-fiction

This was one of those things I had on 10-15 years ago as background noise while totally invested in some Gameboy game and ended up watching bits and pieces of. May have been a movie, a mini-series marathon (I do remember it being oddly long) or a multi episode story arc of a running series at the time. I have no idea what channel it may have been on but my guess is Sci-Fi (definitely pre-SyFy).

The only details I remember are the one mentioned in the question itself, of a girl being slid down a narrowing tube as a means of killing her (don't remember if she actually died), and one character (possibly the same girl) using "Wicked" as a sort of catchphrase. If I recall correctly the show had a sort of dystopian future feel and a dark goth aesthetic. It definitely seemed 90s or early 00s but my memory is a little fuzzy there. The work in question was in English, but i'm not sure from where as I don't remember what accents, if distinctive at all, the characters spoke in.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like [Tank Girl](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114614/)

There is a scene where Malcolm McDowell's character puts a girl in said tube upside down and starts to fill it with water, it's pretty far in, close to the end.

Answer (score 2):

**Tank Girl** is also a dystopian future:

> In 2022, a comet strikes Earth causing an 11-year drought. By 2033, most of the little remaining water is held in reserve by Kesslee (Malcolm McDowell) and his Water & Power (W&P) corporation, which uses the water to control the population. Rebecca Buck – "Tank Girl" (Lori Petty) – is a member of a commune in the Australian outback that operates the last water well not controlled by the corporation. [Wikipedia: Tank Girl (2011)]

I don't suppose you recall if there were any mutants or animated segments?

Comment: Its already present as an answer